# "prime factorisation" of lattice in a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I try to solve an exercice.

Let's $p$ be a prime number and $M$ a lattice of $V$ a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. We denote $M_p$ the set of all $x \in V$ that verify the following condition: it exists an $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ which is not a multiple of $p$ such that $rx \in M$.

I try to show that $M_p$ is a submodule of V which can be seen as a module over $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}= \left\{ \frac ab\in \mathbb Q\mid a,b\in \mathbb Z,p\nmid b \right\}$.

So my first attempt was to show that if $a,b \in M_p$ and $\lambda, \gamma \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, then $\lambda a -\gamma b \in M_p$. But even  with $\gamma= 0$, i don't see how to handle it. Can anyone provide a hint or a solution?

Comment: Multiply first with the product of denominators of $\lambda$ and $\gamma$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the first comment, i try to provide an answer. This post is also related to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2205009/412456).

Suppose that $M$ contains a basis $\{e_1,e_2, \dots ,e_k\}$ of $V$.

Let's $a \in M_p$ and $x_a = \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i e_i \in V$ with $\alpha_i=\frac{\beta_i}{\gamma_i} \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$. We can found $r_a\in \mathbb{Z}\backslash(p)$ such that  $a=r_ax_a=\sum_{i=1}^kr_a\frac {\theta_i}{r_a}e_i$, with $r_a= \prod\limits_{j = 1}^k\gamma_j$ and $\theta_i= \beta_i\prod\limits_{j = 1,\ j\neq i }^k \gamma_j$.
If we multiply $a$ with $\lambda_a \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, we can still find an $r'_a\in\mathbb{Z}\backslash(p)$ such that $\lambda_aa = r'_ax_a$. And the same if we choose $-\lambda_a$.

Putting everything together, we can show that $\lambda a-\gamma b\in M_p$ by expressing the equation at the same denominator.