# Lattice in vector space over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is this proposition true?

> If $M$ is a lattice of $V$, a vector space over $\mathbb Q$, then for each $x \in V$, there exists a $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ not equal to zero such that $rx \in M$.

If yes, how can we show that?

Comment: Let me write more correctly my previous comment. Let $\pi : V \to V/M$ the projection to the quotient, which is a finite abelian group with order $r$. $r\pi(x) = 0$ by definition, so $\pi(rx) = 0$ i.e $rx \in M$.

Comment: If you use the definition of lattice I know, then this is trivial: multiply with a common denominator of a basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the de second comment, i provide an answer.

According to one definition, $M$ is a lattice of $V$ if $M$ is a finite subgroup of the additive group $V$ and if $M$ contains a basis of $V$.

Then suppose $M$ contains a basis $\{e_1,e_2, \dots ,e_k\}$ of $V$. Then any $x \in V$ can be written as $x = \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i e_i$ with $\alpha_i= \frac {\beta_i}{\gamma_i}\in \mathbb{Q}$. Putting everything to the same denominateur, we get $x =\sum_{i=1}^k \frac {\theta_i}{\prod\limits_{j = 1}^k \gamma_j} e_i$ with $\theta_i= \alpha_i\prod\limits_{j = 1,\ j\neq i }^k \gamma_j$.

So we found $r= \prod\limits_{j = 1}^k \gamma_j$. To prove that it is a sub group of the additive group, we want to show that if $r_1x_1$ and $r_2x_2$ are in $M$, then $r_1x_1-r_2x_2 \in M$. This can be showed also by expressing both with same denominator in the basis.